# Custom WPBakery elements not displaying in WP admin

Tags: plugins, php

I'm creating custom elements for **WPBakery**.

I have a folder called `vc-elements` which contains two files:

1. `hero.php`
2. `text-image.php`

On the WordPress admin side, I want both elements to be visible. To do this, in `functions.php` I'm running:

```
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_before_init_actions' );

function vc_before_init_actions() {

    // Link to VC elements's folder
    if( function_exists('vc_set_shortcodes_templates_dir') ){ 
        vc_set_shortcodes_templates_dir( get_template_directory() . 'vc-elements' );
    }
}
```

But in the admin side, neither of the two blocks show?

Previously I had:

```
function vc_before_init_actions() {
    require_once( get_template_directory().'/vc-elements/hero.php' );  
}
```

Which showed the hero block in the admin. But when I added:

```
function vc_before_init_actions() {
    require_once( get_template_directory().'/vc-elements/hero.php' );
    require_once( get_template_directory().'/vc-elements/text-image.php' ); 
}
```

In the admin side, the hero element is replaced by the text image element - only one shows at one time. Why's this?